# Is it possible to get an array as one matching group in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

> Members: {'name': A, 'age': 30, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.56}, {'name': C, 'age': 20, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.8}, {'name': H, 'age': 45, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.97}, {'name': D, 'age': 23, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.68}; Place: 1//Members: {'name': S, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.4}, {'name': C, 'age': 19, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.67}, {'name': A, 'age': 44, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.92}, {'name': C, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.57}; Place: 2

I would like to know if it is possible/how to have a match like:

```
[['30', '20', '45', '23', '1'], ['33', '19', '44', '33', '2']] or

[(['30', '20', '45', '23'], '1'), (['33', '19', '44', '33'], '2')]
```

Or something similar (the resulting structure doesn't really matter) I just need to have all the ages from one Place. I know that I can iterate doing split and apply regex for each part or similar solution, but my question is if there's a way to do it once (ONE single step) using regex...

I would use findall to get all the "full matches". My issue is to get the first parameter of the "tuple" as an array...

If I do:

```
r = re.compile("'age': (\d+).*?; Place: (\d+).*?//")
g = r.findall("Members: {'name': A, 'age': 30, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.56}, {'name': C, 'age': 20, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.8}, {'name': H, 'age': 45, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.97}, {'name': D, 'age': 23, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.68}; Place: 1//Members: {'name': S, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.4}, {'name': C, 'age': 19, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.67}, {'name': A, 'age': 44, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.92}, {'name': C, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.57}; Place: 2")
```

I am only able to get the first age, and then the place...

```
g
[('30', '1')]
```

Comment: You may easily get them with two steps: 1) extract places capturing the part with ages and the Places number ([`('age': .*?;) Place: (\d+).*?(?://|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/v15EzG/2)), 2) extract ages from Group 1 of the previous matches ([`'age':\s*(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/v15EzG/3/)).

Comment: I know that it can be done in two steps... my question though is if it is possible to do it once...

Comment: Yes, but with a `regex` PyPi module only. With `re`, you will have to add some more programming logic to get the results like you want.

Comment: @Gabrielle. I think you need to make it much clearer what the acceptable output would be. The first of the two examples you've given is ambiguous (since it doesn't match the input), and the second looks too complicated (since it nests lists inside tuples). What is the ***most minimal*** acceptable output?

Comment: @ekhumoro as I said in the question, it doesn't really matter because in the first example I can say that the last number is the Place, in the second I just used the return that is the default from findall... tuples of groups... the "only difference" is that one of the groups is an array, which is exactly my question. Both examples  matches the input...

Comment: @Gabrielle. But that would mean that, say, `['30', '20', '45', '23', '1', '', '33', '19', '44', '33', '2', '']`, is acceptable output, since the elements **are** separated into groups, to some extent. If you insist on a single regex, it is unrealistic to expect complicated data structures as output, unless you allow for at least one additional pass (to split up the results).

Comment: @ekhumoro this thing you put your comment, in my scenario, it is acceptable. The complex structure you are referring to I only used because the common behaviour of findall with more than one group is to put [(group1, group2), (group1, group2)] and that's why I've used it. My question is exactly this. Can I make group1 (for example) to be an array? Does Regex supports it? That is what I don't know

Comment: @ekhumoro If this is not possible, then, the other answer (for my scenario) can be `['30', '20', '45', '23', '1', '', '33', '19', '44', '33', '2', '']`, and then, in this case, how can I obtain this?

Comment: @Gabrielle. Shall I post an answer that gives this output, and also suggest a reasonably simple way to split it up with a second pass?

Comment: @ekhumoro Sure :) I think the main question was if it is possible to come with the second scenario, if it's not, than, the other solution is to do it in a second step and/or do as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know RegEx is not powerful enough to store the hits of one capturing group with a quantifier in a list, followed by another capturing group.

The following does only perform one RegEx search, and one loop, but I admit it isn't very pretty.

```
import re

r = re.compile("(age|Place)'?: (\d+)")

g = r.finditer("Members: {'name': A, 'age': 30, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.56}, {'name': C, 'age': 20, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.8}, {'name': H, 'age': 45, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.97}, {'name': D, 'age': 23, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.68}; Place: 1//Members: {'name': S, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.4}, {'name': C, 'age': 19, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.67}, {'name': A, 'age': 44, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.92}, {'name': C, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.57}; Place: 2")

ages = []
ranks = {}
for m in g:
  if m[1] == 'age':
    ages.append(m[2])
  else:
    ranks[m[2]] = ages
    ages = []

print(ranks)
```

Basically just capture any age or Place, iterate over the matches. Store all ages into a list until we come across a Place, in which case we use the former list as a value and the Place as a key in a dictionary. Then we reset the list and start over.

Of course the caveat is that Place always comes *after* the ages.

Comment: I think this answers my question... not the code but this part: "RegEx is not powerful enough to store the hits of one capturing group with a quantifier in a list, followed by another capturing group."

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to get close to a solution using `re.findall` and `itertools.groupby`:

```
import re, itertools
r = re.compile(r'(?:\b(?:age|place)\'?\s*:\s*(\d+))|//|\Z', re.I)
x = r.findall("Members: {'name': A, 'age': 30, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.56}, {'name': C, 'age': 20, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.8}, {'name': H, 'age': 45, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.97}, {'name': D, 'age': 23, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.68}; Place: 1//Members: {'name': S, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.4}, {'name': C, 'age': 19, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.67}, {'name': A, 'age': 44, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.92}, {'name': C, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.57}; Place: 2")
```

Output:

```
['30', '20', '45', '23', '1', '', '33', '19', '44', '33', '2', '']
```

Splitting with a second pass:

```
o = [list(g[1]) for g in itertools.groupby(x, lambda i: i != '')][::2]
```

Output:

```
[['30', '20', '45', '23', '1'], ['33', '19', '44', '33', '2']]
```

Comment: I think this solves my issue, I can have a huge string following the mentioned pattern, so I didn't want to split and than iterate over it because I think it would take too much time, I (think) this is quicker because the second iteration is over a much smaller set

Answer (score 0):

```
[re.findall("(\d+)", i) for i in re.split("//", "Members: {'name': A, 'age': 30, 'gender': M}, {'name': C, 'age': 20, 'gender': M}, {'name': H, 'age': 45, 'gender': M}, {'name': D, 'age': 23, 'gender': M}; Place: 1//Members: {'name': S, 'age': 33, 'gender': M}, {'name': C, 'age': 19, 'gender': M}, {'name': A, 'age': 44, 'gender': M}, {'name': C, 'age': 33, 'gender': M}; Place: 2")]
[['30', '20', '45', '23', '1'], ['33', '19', '44', '33', '2']]
```

Comment: I might have other fields. I've edited my question in order to show I can have more numbers other than the ones I need. Also, as pointed by @ekhumoro, I need the values grouped.

Comment: Try the modified solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my go at it:

```
import re
test_str = "Members: {'name': A, 'age': 30, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.56}, {'name': C, 'age': 20, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.8}, {'name': H, 'age': 45, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.97}, {'name': D, 'age': 23, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.68}; Place: 1//Members: {'name': S, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.4}, {'name': C, 'age': 19, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.67}, {'name': A, 'age': 44, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.92}, {'name': C, 'age': 33, 'gender': M, 'height': 1.57}; Place: 2"

# regex patterns
test_pattern_age = "'age': \d+"
test_pattern_place = "Place: \d+"
test_pattern_strip_nums = "[^0-9]"

# split our string into chunks based on 'Members:''
test_chunks = test_str.split('Members:') 

# our return dict
ret_dict = {};

for chunk in test_chunks:
  temp_place_list = re.findall(test_pattern_place,chunk)
  if len(temp_place_list) > 0:
    temp_place = re.sub(test_pattern_strip_nums, "", temp_place_list[0])
    test_list = re.findall(test_pattern_age,chunk)
    temp_age_list = []
    for x in test_list:
      temp_age_list.append(re.sub(test_pattern_strip_nums, "", x))
    ret_dict[temp_place] = temp_age_list  

  else:
    pass


print(ret_dict)
```

It is certainly not the *sexiest* way of doing things, but essentially you are splitting the original string into chunks (here I did it based on 'Members:' - but it could be places or something else) and then from each 'chunk' getting the place and ages and sticking them into a dict.

The resulting dict prints this:

```
{'1': ['30', '20', '45', '23'], '2': ['33', '19', '44', '33']}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I know that I could split or use more than one regex, applied in different steps.. I was looking for a single regex (one single step) that generates the required output... but as mentioned by @BramVanroy I don't think it is possible....

Comment: I see - yeah I'm not sure if that is possible. One additional thing - can I ask why you are handling what looks to be JSON as one big string rather than a JSON object? Were you handling it as a string as a way of trying to apply the regex to it?

Comment: I have a log file that mixes json with other strings; The main point is because I have different threads (that I cannot operate with several locks) changing the same log file, but I can't have all of the information as one single json because I would have to convert several times to use and save, so, the solution was to come with a hybrid solution.. I know this isn't the best scenario though